# Разные size, position для :nth-child

Tags: jquery

задать разные size, position для :nth-child
пример http://kavko.ru/old/index.html 
что  нужно исправить?
http://jsfiddle.net/VGPt8/6/

Comment: зачем вам там :nth-child... ` $("ul li img").eq(index).css({`

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/VGPt8/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(" + index + ")")
```

Исправить на это (спасибо [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto) за подсказку об улучшении):

```
$("ul li img").eq(index)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/VGPt8/11/

Comment: спасибо внес иправление http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/VGPt8/7/